# How to write two python dictionaries to a single csv?

Tags: python, csv, merge

Can anyone please tell me how to write two `dict`s to a single csv?
I tried with one dict:

```
import csv

my_dict = {"test": 1, "testing": 2}

with open('mycsvfile.csv', 'wb') as f:  # Just use 'w' mode in 3.x
    w = csv.DictWriter(f, my_dict.keys())
    w.writeheader()
    w.writerow(my_dict)
```

But when I tried with two `dict`:

```
import csv

my_dict1 = {"test": 1, "testing": 2}
my_dict2 = {"test": 3, "testing": 4}

my_dict =my_dict1,my_dict2
with open('mycsvfile.csv', 'wb') as f:  # Just use 'w' mode in 3.x
    w = csv.DictWriter(f, my_dict1.keys())
    w.writeheader()
    w.writerow(my_dict)
```

That doesn't work :(

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `csv.DictWriter` object has a [writerows](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.csvwriter.writerows) method that meets your needs:

```
import csv

my_dict1 = {"test": 1, "testing": 2}
my_dict2 = {"test": 3, "testing": 4}

my_dicts = my_dict1,my_dict2

with open('mycsvfile.csv', 'wb') as f:  # Just use 'w' mode in 3.x
    w = csv.DictWriter(f, my_dict1.keys())
    w.writeheader()
    w.writerows(my_dicts)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just invoke `writerow` multiple times assuming they have the same keys.

```
import csv

my_dict1 = {"test": 1, "testing": 2}
my_dict2 = {"test": 3, "testing": 4}

with open('mycsvfile.csv', 'wb') as f:  # Just use 'w' mode in 3.x
    w = csv.DictWriter(f, my_dict1.keys())
    w.writeheader()
    w.writerow(my_dict1)
    w.writerow(my_dict2)
```